# How to position a Leaflet js DivIcon?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, web, leaflet

I have been trying to place a rotated icon on my markers in Leaflet. The white square in the picture shows where my marker image should be but the blue marker is far from this position. How can I get the blue marker to be placed exactly where the white square is? My Code:

```
    var myIcon = L.divIcon({ 
    html:'<img src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.3/images/marker-icon.png" id="image">',
    });

    L.marker([5000.000, 5000.000],{ icon: myIcon }).addTo(map);
```

[Leaflet Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXEEa.jpg)

Comment: You need to position at the latLng and set the right iconAnchor properties. If you want to use pixel coordinates, check out the map.project and map.unproject methods.